# R duplicating predictor variables with glm and categorical variables

Tags: r, glm

I am building a glm in R with categorical predictors and a binary response. My data is like this (but much bigger and with multiple predictors):

```
y <- c(1,1,1,0,0) #response
x <- c(0,0,0,1,2) #predictor
```

Since this data is categorical (but it is represented by numbers), I did this:

```
y <- as.factor(y)
x <- as.factor(x)
```

And then I built my model:

```
g1 <- glm(y~x, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

But the details of the model are the following:

```
g1
Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
      24.57       -49.13       -49.13  
Degrees of Freedom: 4 Total (i.e. Null);  2 Residual
Null Deviance:      6.73 
Residual Deviance: 2.143e-10    AIC: 6
```

And the summary is:

```
summary(g1)
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

Deviance Residuals: 
         1           2           3           4           5  
 6.547e-06   6.547e-06   6.547e-06  -6.547e-06  -6.547e-06  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     24.57   75639.11       0        1
x1             -49.13  151278.15       0        1
x2             -49.13  151278.15       0        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 6.7301e+00  on 4  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.1434e-10  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 23
```

What I don't understand is why R has duplicated the x predictor in x1 and x2? What do x1 and x2 mean?

I also need to explicitly write down the model with the estimates, something of the form: y ~ B0 + B1*x so I am stuck now because x has been divided in two and there are no initial variables called x1 and x2...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have made `x` a factor. This factor has three levels (0, 1 and 2). When you put a categorical variable in a regression model, one way of coding it is to use a reference category. In this case R has chosen to make the 0 level the reference category. Then  the coefficients of x1 and x2 are the difference in the levels between 0 and 1 as well as 0 and 2 respectively.

This is pretty standard in regression so you shouldn't find it too surprising. Perhaps you were just confused about how R named the coefficients.